# QR scan in a half screen using zxing library xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, qr-code, zxing

In Xamarin android QR scan using zxing is much easy as it requires only 3 lines of codes.
`MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
var result = await scanner.Scan();
string qrCode = result.ToString();`

But it always opens a default view with full screen even if I set it inside oncreate event or button click. What I really need is having qr scan in half screen instead of full screen. remaining othert half screen will be used to add few buttons.

If anyone knows how to do it please let me know I have spent more than 3-4 days to find the answer for this component. Also if there are any other useful library than zxing for qr scanning let me know.

Thanks,
Muthu

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile#using-the-zxingscanner-view--fragment--control

Comment: Hi It doesn't give a solution for my question. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You might want to actually look at the samples mentioned, as `ZxingSurfaceView` in `ZXingActivity.cs` does exactly what you are asking for

Comment: does zamarin supports libraries built for native android apps? Iy yes, you can use the following library : https://github.com/nipun-birla/QRReaderView

Comment: Yes! It helped.Thank you @SushiHangover

Comment: @SushiHangover I am kind of struggled with device back button press event. I create the qr scan window using LayoutInflater as Redth has explained in Zxing. when I try to create back button press as he did it works. But my primary goal is when qr scanned success trigger some other function and only when back button pressed close the application. But it doesn't work properly. I will add my code segment here.

Comment: scanner.CustomOverlay = zxingOverlay;
var result = await scanner.Scan();
//HandleScanResult(result);
 var output = result.ToString();
QRscan(output);

Comment: But in above code HandlescanResult works when I click back button only if I comment two last code lines. I want to have that two lines and back button press ability both. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SushiHangover mentioned, use the `ZXingScannerFragment` to achieve this. Take a look at the sample [here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/0dc587690f1b88194ed5ae49e61a61aae74e6a75/Samples/Android/Sample.Android/FragmentActivity.cs).

Comment: Yes I used it. Thanks

Comment: This sample appears to be broken, or not up to date. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: It's from Nov 2016. What isn't working? Do you get an exception? Did you check logcat? Did you initialize the library? Did you add permission handling to your activity? Have you read the ZXing.Net.Mobile [readme](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/readme.md) and confirmed you've set everything up properly?

Comment: @TrevorBalcom There are multiple issues raised at the ZXing GitHub; instantiating a ZXingScannerFragment object and attempting to replace a view with it doesn’t start the scan, because the transaction commit doesn’t complete in time. See this: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/612